# How to make swipe tabs layout inside a fragment of a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am following the official android tutorial to insert swiping tabs layout in a fragment of my navigation drawer.

```
    import com.example.android.supportv4.
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

/**
 * This demonstrates how you can implement switching between the tabs of a
 * TabHost through fragments, using FragmentTabHost.
 */
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

Please help me understand what is the "**R.id.realtabcontent**". 
How do I make the XML layout of this fragment ?

Comment: Depends on the method 'setup'. Post the code of that method and explain what exactly does not work.

Comment: well..a working XML layout ?

Answer (score 0):

R.id.realtabcontent is ID of FragmentTabHost. Below is a simple working xml for **"fragment_tabs.xml"**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
  <TabWidget
     android:id="@android:id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <FrameLayout
     android:id="@android:id/tab_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout></android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```